# How to change text on the span use vue.js 2?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false" :title="...">
            ...
            <span v-if="totalNotif > 0" class="badge" id="total-notif">{{ totalNotif }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.initialMount()
        },
        ...
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'totalNotif'
            ])
        },
        methods: {
            initialMount() {
                Echo.private('App.User.' + window.Laravel.authUser.id).notification((notification) => {
                    const totalNotif = $('#total-notif').text()
                    const totalNotifNew = parseInt(totalNotif) + 1
                    $('#total-notif').text(totalNotifNew )
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works

But, it still use jquery to get and update text on the span

How can I do it using vue.js 2?

I read some references, that it using `watch`. But I am still confused to use it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const totalNotif = $('#total-notif').text()
const totalNotifNew = parseInt(totalNotif) + 1
$('#total-notif').text(totalAllNew)
```

By

```
//Set this.totalNotif to 1 if not exist or equals to 0. Else increment by 1
this.totalNotif = (this.totalNotif) ? (this.totalNotif + 1) : 1;
```

But I don't understand the code :

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'totalNotif'
        ])
    },
```

For my example I think you can have :

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.initialMount()
    },
    data() {
       return {
           totalNotif: 0
       }
    },
    ...
```

Comment: This : `computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'totalNotif'
        ])
    },`. It used to take total notif from the database. If I follow your step, total notif = 0

Comment: Now the problem is how to combine that with a total notif from the database?

Comment: Maybe create a method to call AJAX to get notalNotif from database and call this method in mounted() function of Vue. If you don't use jQuery you can use axios for your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

On the template you will change the span with:

```
<span v-if="totalNotif > 0" class="badge" id="total-notif" v-text="totalNotif"></span>
```

This will connect `span` with value `totalNotif`.
So on VueJs part, remove jquery part, updating only data `totalNotif` and automatically will update span text content.

EDIT
To better understand, the script part become:

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.initialMount()
    },

    data() {
       return {
          totalNotif: 0
       }
    },

    methods: {
        initialMount() {
            Echo.private('App.User.' + window.Laravel.authUser.id).notification((notification) => {
                this.totalNotif = this.totalNotif + 1

            })
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you found the "v-text" directive ?

Comment: @g.annunziata, This : `computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'totalNotif'
        ])
    },`. It used to take total notif from the database. If I follow your step, total notif = 0

Comment: @g.annunziata, Now the problem is how to combine that with a total notif from the database?

Comment: you can read on method `initialMount()`: you can call REST to get value from db and set directly `this.totalNotif = dbValue`